# High quality publishing house for books in the field of statistics

Tags: references

What are important/notable publishing houses for books in statistics?

When I come across a book published at O'Reilly or Springer I imagine its quality will be high.  What other notable publishing houses are out there (for statistics books)?  Any recommendation on a way to find out? (I'd imagine we could check it if we had the database dump of amazon, but I don't imagine something like that is available anywhere...)

Comment: @Tal Should we set this as CW?

Comment: Yes chl - that would be great.

Comment: Chapman Hall / CRC and Wiley also publish quality statistics texts.  But one shouldn't judge a book by its publisher...

Comment: I find that even within a publisher there's often a pretty wide range of offerings. Authorship is usually a much better indicator; I bet I could pull down any book I love and find one published by the same house that I hate.

Comment: I'm not the biggest fan of O'Reilly when it comes to statistics. O'Reilly's book on R (the owl book) is designed for a much less technical audience. The Springer texts are really pretty fantastic, and one of the more reliable sources. Wiley (Clinical Trials, Categorical Data Analysis) and ChapmanHall/CRC (Gelman's Bayesian book) too. Between those three, you've got a fair sample of statistics.

Comment: Does the question relate to content, or things like typesetting and paper quality?

Comment: Most university presses.

Answer (score 4):

Well, [here is a list](http://www.amstat.org/meetings/jsm/2011/index.cfm?fuseaction=exhibitors) of the companies that paid to exhibit at the most recent (2011) Joint Statistical Meetings.  This includes a lot of publishers.  I am not sure why a major publisher would *not* be at the biggest statistical meeting in the world, or at least at the largest one to draw a lot of different teachers and researchers from a large span of areas.

There's Springer, OUP, Sage, Wiley, W.H. Freeman, Elsevier, CRC, SIAM, CUP, BEP...

Did I miss anyone?

Note that some of these are conglomerates and may have different publishers or different series under the same umbrella firm.

By the way, O'Reilly is not a major statistics publisher.  While I have a lot of their books, I don't turn to any of them for statistical insights.  I am not sure they have any statistical editors, for that matter, but they do a good job on books on programming.

Answer (score 2):

Another good one is Sage, which produces hundreds of small monographs in the Quantitative Applications in the Social Sciences series.